# Why are Laravel models using so much memory?

Tags: php, laravel, optimization, eloquent

Looking for ways to reduce the amount of memory used, I found the following model behavior described below. I want to understand the reasons for this.

My model:

```
class Video extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = [
        'article_id',
        'url',
        'source',
    ];
}
```

Case 1:

```
$memoryStart = memory_get_usage();

$videoModel = Video::first();

$memory = memory_get_usage() - $memoryStart;
$this->info(round($memory / 1024 / 1024, 2));
```

Result: **1.9**

Case 2:

```
$memoryStart = memory_get_usage();

$videoAttributes = DB::table('videos')->first();
$videoModel = new Video((array)$videoAttributes);

$memory = memory_get_usage() - $memoryStart;
$this->info(round($memory / 1024 / 1024, 2));
```

Result: **1.11**

Why such a difference? and what is the risk of using the 2nd option for optimization?

Comment: Second option is just ugly, but you can do a simple `var_dump` of each instance and see what properties you do not have. It will boil down to not having some relation loaded, or property or similar. If you have `xdebug`, you can still check each property of the object live